# HMC197BE| GaAs MMIC SOT26 SPDT SWITCH| do not “hot switch” power levels

Tags: integrated-circuit, switching

I came across a datasheet that says:
[image: http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc197b.pdf]

I want to know what does this: **"do not “hot switch” power levels
greater than +20 dBm (Vctl = +5Vdc)"** means.

Based on its truth table, I "assume" that it is forbidden to simultaneously apply +5V on both control inputs. 
[image: http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc197b.pdf]

The device here is a HMC197BE, GaAs MMIC SOT26 SPDT SWITCH. 
Here is the link to the datasheet: http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc197b.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The device gate junction  may be damaged by reactive voltage coupling effects of DC during high RF conduction. The step function should be avoided